# Get XML value based on condition via XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Below is my XML:

```
<bookstore>
   <book>
      <title>Python</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>XML</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
      <feature>
           <description>Learn XML</description>
      </feature>
   </book>
</bookstore>
```

If the `description` `"Learn XML"` is matched, then it should return the `title` `"XML"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath

```
//description[text() = 'Learn XML']/../../title
```

It matches all `description` elements with `text()` content of "Learn XML" and gets its `title`.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//book[feature/description="Learn XML"]/title
```

will return `title` elements of books whose `feature/description` is `"Learn XML"`.